# Proof of logarithmic asymptotic identity

Tags: calculus, logarithms, asymptotics

I saw the following identity [here](https://twitter.com/ccanonne_/status/1540787980268457984):
$$
\log(a\,b) = \Theta(\log(a + b)) = c\log(a + b),
$$
for any $a,b>1$ and some constant $c>0$ independent of $a,b$.
Could someone provide any hints why this holds?

**Update:** $\Theta$ refers to the asymptotic Landau notation, and in this context just hides a constant independent of $a,b$.

Comment: What is $\Theta$?

Comment: @DavidSheard: $\Theta$ refers to the asymptotic Landau notation. Here, it just hides a constant, i.e., $\log(a b) = c \log(a + b)$, for some suitable constant $c>0$ that is independent of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Arun please edit your question to include the full information.

Comment: @SuzuHirose: Done